# In cocos2d-x, what is difference between atlas and sprite-sheet?

Tags: cocos2d-x, sprite-sheet, atlas

I'm new to `cocos2d-x` game development engine

but I don't understand what is the difference between Atlas and sprite-sheet.

are they the same thing or not?

Comment: Please take a [look](http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/creator/manual/en/asset-workflow/atlas.html), it may be help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Atlas` is like a generic object if you want to render fast a grouped of images from a single image file like, bitmap labels, spritesheet, multi-image particle, etc.

`SpriteSheet` is one of those objects that uses functionality of `Atlas` to render its images fast.